# How do I prevent text surrounded by a border from breaking to the next line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to program a small web page (for a class, not for real) and I'm encountering a strange problem. There's some text that is in boxes. I put the code in for a border around the text, but it causes a line break and goes to the next line. Here's what the code looks like:

```
Address: <p style="border-style: solid; width: 250px;">
487, street 1, 8th block, Brig, Indiana
<br>
Phone: 555555555
</p>
```

Now whenever I run it, the box around the address is on the next line, instead of next to the word "Address:" and I can't figure out why. How can I stop this, and get it on the same line?

Comment: Fix your code example please.

Comment: The `<p></p>` means paragraph, so it always does a line break before starting the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `<p>` is a [block element](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/). Hence it will always start from a new line. Try making it an [`inline-block`](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/) element, like this:

```
<p style="border-style: solid;
          width: 250px;
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: middle;">
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdm3p/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#div { 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```